# Mule Change flowVars String date format using Expression Component

Tags: mule, esb, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb

I am passing inputDate : **2017-06-27 16:46:36** And

I want to convert format to **27-June-2017**

**Using Expression Component**

I am trying this

```
flowVars.inputDate = new org.mule.el.datetime.DateTime(new Date(flowVars.inputDate),"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use dataweave script for the same in two ways

1:

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
<dw:set-variable variableName="inputDate"><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
flowVars.inputDate as :localdatetime {format:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'} as :string {format:'dd-MMMM-yyyy'}]]></dw:set-variable>
</dw:transform-message>
```

2:

```
<set-variable variableName="inputDate" value="#[dw(&quot;flowVars.inputDate as :localdatetime {format:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'} as :string {format:'dd-MMMM-yyyy'}&quot;)]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve desired result from an expression component

```
<expression-component doc:name="Expression"><![CDATA[String date_s = "2017-06-27 16:46:36"; 
java.text.SimpleDateFormat dt = new  java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"); 
java.util.Date date = dt.parse(date_s); 
java.text.SimpleDateFormat dt1 =  new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
flowVars.inputDt = dt1.format(date);]]></expression-component>
        <logger message="-------#[flowVars.inputDt]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
```